# Obfuscated Malicious PHP

Tags: php, security

I found [this code](http://pastebin.com/PfbacsHT) on a hacked Drupal installation, and I'd like to know what the code was capable of doing. I've tried various tools to de-obfuscate it, but I've been unsuccessful. I'm getting tripped up with the $r76 variable. I can't figure out how it's encoded. Translation or suggestions?

```
<?php $r76="F[<PAlDf|]}M@~79/O8Kx\rH6r&-c5k\n3X,YzhQ> Cp\\wUu2jGoB;0i_SN\tn%Vg)ZI^sTRyvL{\$:=1*mE+JW(q4.t'`a!\"#edb?";
```

Comment: It's a cipher key. Access bits and letters of the string using array access through the rest of the code and you can construct a completely different string from it.

Comment: In and of itself, the thing you posted is nothing but a string. The parts in pastebin reference it like `$r76[24]` since you can access characters of a string by index.  It's basically a bag of characters that the rest of the obfuscation draws from to build up other variables and strings.  As in: `$string = 'abcde'; echo $string[2];` --> prints `c`

Comment: Most important thing is to take this Drupal site offline and restore it from backup, rather than worry much about what the evil code is doing.

Comment: For just a sample, from the example, `$r76[94].$r76[24].$r76[24].$r76[49].$r76[24].$r76[54].$r76[24].$r76[94].$r76[41].$r76[49].$r76[24].$r76[87].$r76[53].$r76[58].$r76[61]` == `error_reporting`. Agreed though, just cut the code out - it has no value to you.

Comment: It means precisely... dick.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You mean `$r76[6].$r76[53].$r76[27].$r76[29]`?

Comment: @sjagr Decoding that was enterprising of you.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Slow day at the office. My life has purpose now

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The site was scanned, and this was the only malicious code found. I immediately downloaded the file and removed it from the server. The Drupal admin and database passwords were also changed.

Comment: @sjagr How did you translate the numbers in brackets to characters?

Comment: @GrayLoon I let PHP evaluate them.

Comment: Nevermind. Rereading the above comment, I figured out that r76[24] refers to the 24th character of the $r76 variable. Duh.

Comment: @GrayLoon (technically the _25th_ character -- zero-based arrays :-) )

Answer (score 2):

`$r76` is a cipher key. Access bits and letters of the string using array access through the rest of the code and you can construct a completely different string (like function names, variables, etc.) from it.

Here are the evaluations for the globals that were defined at the top of the script. Use them to figure out the rest of the script... if you feel like wasting any more time on this than I did:

```
[vtton6] => error_reporting
[jlxru64] => ini_set
[vajox38] => define
[qobdl72] => hvcug13
[yhrfr40] => xyhxn92
[quzii24] => md5
[tlyiy12] => count
[kyioa8] => time
[glyac65] => constant
[nhnww15] => npufi61
[igajs32] => potcc11
[cpukq94] => omauf87
[bdonk12] => hwgbo88
[aurku4] => ioxgo29
[yqqkt30] => function_exists
[tnmsd36] => mail
[chqql44] => armtx32
[cvtxr40] => ecyws30
[eavur97] => usleep
[ptlaz26] => urvfu78
[xcnkh30] => xllez0
[wnlxd28] => trim
[laepm94] => preg_replace
[nxseo15] => gethostbyname
[cyzbs96] => preg_match
[yoejz48] => rzekg39
[lzjpr73] => wdtjf68
[osnjl91] => rxrmp70
[zhjzv93] => prcux47
[brkww19] => strlen
[yhcum29] => oyysg80
[ibere91] => foftg27
[vszxc90] => array_keys
[qtgcq90] => socket_select
[bwpvf88] => ucfirst
[bdvxl14] => str_replace
[xizmx47] => ini_get
[stkuy98] => vkaqq98
[duiid33] => date
[grxdw62] => getmxrr
[nvuxa92] => ybewy88
[ysmvf63] => min
[vbhwy58] => Array
    (
    )

[wdbfr89] => fewfx40
[vxogc32] => preg_split
[inenw32] => xwses24
[xyxdn38] => chr
[rtdlc97] => ord
[cnrfe78] => urldecode
[wzekj92] => stripslashes
[yrqxp89] => array_flip
[xavtv19] => preg_match_all
[zjheh80] => base64_encode
[gisxn89] => socket_create
[oqikt29] => socket_last_error
[tvxvt28] => socket_strerror
[fmlld76] => socket_set_option
[zwafy86] => socket_set_nonblock
[uocvp26] => socket_connect
[xvxof76] => fsockopen
[vzqix48] => stream_set_blocking
[sltum36] => stream_set_timeout
[clkxn20] => stream_socket_client
[unkvq75] => socket_close
[yoxhh65] => fclose
[dskbo69] => socket_read
[jhtbn88] => feof
[zflfl64] => fread
[uwnpx27] => socket_write
[stdvp96] => fwrite
[ocmvf65] => rand
[bkenc7] => explode
[llpxl21] => pack
[efljc33] => unpack
[zndda55] => cgzhg7
[lzlla40] => array_merge
[axqrn63] => long2ip
```

If I had to guess, the mention of `mail` in the obfuscated variables just means that this is a malicious mailing script designed to turn your PHP server into a spam server - or maybe it's a "phone home" functionality for much more evil purposes.

Comment: Re: previous comment `s/enterprising/reckless/` :-P  YOLO, I guess.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Nah, I regex'ed `GLOBALS\['([^']+?)']` and replaced it into local vars, then evaluated everything up until `@$vtton6` (the first attempt at a function call or script execution.) Then `print_r(get_defined_vars())` and voila.

Comment: Ugh, `GLOBALS\['([^']+?)'\]` (forgot to escape a character - [_wheeeeee-taptaptap-eeee!_](http://xkcd.com/208/))

Comment: @sjagr Could you paste the code you used to regex those variables?

Comment: @GrayLoon [I didn't use code](http://www.sublimetext.com/3). Any text editor with regex find/replace will do though. On the replace part, just use `$1`.